# How to remove all lines that start with a certain string using java regex?

Tags: java, regex

There is a text of about 1000 characters.

```
String text = "bla bla..................
               .........................
               .........................
               file.....................
               .........................
               .........................
               file.....................
               .........................
```

Some lines  start with a word "file". How can I remove **ALL** such lines?
Here is what I tried

```
text = text.replaceAll("file.*?//n", "");
```

Comment: Are there line breaks after each row? Or is it just defined in a text initialization broken into multiple rows in code?

Comment: There are line breaks. I simply tried to visually show how it looks like

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You could try the following instead:

```
text = text.replaceAll("(?m)^file.*", "");
```

- `(?m)`: Turns multi-line mode on, so that the start-of-line `^` anchor matches the start of each line.
- `^`: matches the start-of-line.
- `file`: Matches the literal `file` sequence.
- `.*` matches everything to the end of line.

So this look for any line that has the word `file` at the start, then matches the entire line and replaces it with the empty string.

Comment: And if you add `(?:\r?\n)?` at the end, you can remove the newline too. +1

Comment: @Sniffer: thanks but sorry, I have commented a little fast this time, because It doesn't remove the newline if the matched line is at the end of the string.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte LOL, I didn't even think about your comment this time, I took it for granted. Anyway I have removed the quote but thank you nontheless.

Comment: @Sniffer: I was a trap, don't trust anybody!